# Working with two context EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im using EF (Entity Framework Code First) and Repository Patern with Unity (Dependency Injection) and Unit Of Work. I have two context but I want to work with one of them depending of the request. Something like this:

```
public bool Save(User user, RequestTyoe request)
{
```

> //Here apply some pattern that decide depending of request the context
>   to use

```
   AbstracRepository.Add(user);
   AbstracRepository.UnitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Any suggestion ??

PD: Really I dont know what pattern use ...

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand - you have two different contexts that both persist `User`  objects?  What's the difference between the contexts?

Comment: The diference are the number of columns ...

Answer (score 0):

If you generic repository and different context,  then you can specify the type of context you want to pass.

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> : 
    IGenericRepository<T> where T : class where C : DbContext, new()
```

Comment: Ok, I have My Application Layer. in this layer I have a service (`UserService` that implements an interface: `IUserService`) and inside there I have a property: `IUserRepository` (This property is initialized using Unity); now you are tell me that I shoud replace the `IUserRepository` by `IGenericReporitory` in the implementation of my service ??

Comment: well if you want to switch context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CastleWindsor to easily register multiple Services: 
http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

NuGet: http://www.nuget.org/packages/castle.windsor

```
public class UserServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IUserService1>()
            .ImplementedBy<UserService1>()
            .LifestyleTransient());

        container.Register(Component.For<IUserService2>()
            .ImplementedBy<UserService2>()
            .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

Then in your controller you take in the services in your constructor and you can use them however you like.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IUserService1 _userService1;
    private IUserService2 _userService2;

    public MyController(IUserService1 userService1, IUserService2 userService2)
    {
        _userService1 = userService1;
        _userService2 = userService2;
    }
}
```